# Calculate the mean of the Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Mean), the mean of the Binomial distribution is calculated as folllows:

Set $\ell:=k-1$, $m:=n-1$, we get

\begin{align}
\mu
&=\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=np\sum_{\ell=0}^m\binom{m}{\ell}p^\ell(1-p)^{m-\ell}\tag{1}\\
&=np(p+(1-p))^m\tag{2}\\
&=np
\end{align}

What confused me was that how we could get (2) from (1)? i.e. Why $\sum_{\ell=0}^m\binom{m}{\ell}p^l(1-p)^{m-\ell}=(p+(1-p))^m$?

Comment: Are you not familiar with [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) then?

Comment: It is directly derived from the binomial theorem

Comment: @drhab, thanks, the link you provided is very useful.